# Should I go for same box or combine box?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider that you have two boxes: Box 1 and Box 2.

There are 2,536 normal balls & 226 golden balls which makes a total of 2,762 balls in Box 1.

There are 2,024 normal balls & 206 golden balls which makes a total of 2,230 balls in Box 2.

So, we can say that the golden balls it the lucky ball. Hence Box 1 has 8.18% chance of probability to wins golden ball and Box 2 has 9.24%.

Next, the price to buy one ball in Box 1 is 3819 dollars per ball and the 9519 dollars for Box 2. The rules are, you only have $80,000 budget and you can only buy maximum 10 balls, either you combine ball in Box 1 and Box 2, but it must be maximum 10 balls only.

For easier to read, I do make table as below.

| Box | Normal Balls | Golden Balls | Total Balls | Probability (%) | Price per Ball (USD) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Box 1 | 2,536 | 226 | 2,762 | 8.18% | 3,819 |
| Box 2 | 2,024 | 206 | 2,230 | 9.24% | 9,519 |

The target here is:

1. Use the budget as maximum as possible.
2. Increase the chance to win golden ball as much as possible

**I have answered the question, and the answer is to buy 3 balls from Box 1 and 7 balls from Box 2.**

Here is what my lecturer asked:
It is a good probability to buy balls from two Boxes. Because when you buy from two box, the number of opponent that you need to fight will increase. Instead, if you only focused on one box, you have already cut another box of opponent. So, my question here:

1. Does my answer which combines 3 balls in Box 1 and 7 balls in Box 2 is the best?
2. Does taking 10 balls from only Box 1 give the best probability even it not maximizing the budget have but it has cut opponent from Box 2?
3. Does taking 8 balls from only Box 2 give the best probability even it not maximizing the budget have, not maximizing the total number of balls that can be bought, but it has cut opponent from Box 1?

Which one is the best?

Comment: No... always choose from the box that gives the highest probability of a payoff per dollar spent, that is, maximize your expected return per dollar spent.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork So, it should be 8 balls from Box 2?

Comment: There are some details that might change the answer. Regarding the budget: do I pocket what I don't spend in balls? Say that I just spend 50k dollars. The remaining 30k are mine or get burned? How much do I win if I draw a golden ball? What if I draw 2 or more golden balls? The draws are made with or without replacement?